# How to insert a checkbox in a django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've a settings page where users can select if they want to receive a newsletter or not.

I want a checkbox for this, and I want that Django select it if 'newsletter' is true in database. How can I implement in Django?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**models.py:**

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    receive_newsletter = models.BooleanField()
    # ...
```

**forms.py:**

```
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    receive_newsletter = forms.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = Settings
```

And if you want to automatically set `receive_newsletter` to `True` according to some criteria in your application, you account for that in the forms `__init__`:

```
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    receive_newsletter = forms.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self):
        if check_something():
            self.fields['receive_newsletter'].initial  = True

    class Meta:
        model = Settings
```

The boolean form field uses a `CheckboxInput` widget by **default**.

Answer (score 7):

You use a CheckBoxInput widget on your form:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxInput

If you're directly using ModelForms, you just want to use a BooleanField in your model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield

Comment: This is overall a better answer. Less code to write & using django's builtin objects for the job.

Answer (score 3):

```
class PlanYourHouseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PlanYourHouse
        exclude = ['is_deleted'] 
        widgets = {
            'is_anything_required' : CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'required checkbox form-control'}),   
        }
```