# add field to a modelform in django

Tags: django-forms

I have displayed UserCreationForm and user profile form displayed on user registration page.

I want to add a I agree check box on registration page.
When I try to add a field that is not in model django gives error that I agree is not in model.

Any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6195447/2165413) is asked something similar, try to put

```
agree = forms.BooleanField()
```

in your model form. This should work. If not works for you, i need more details