# How to use a checkbox in Django to enter 1 or 0 into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

Using `inspectdb`, I have the following model for a `User` table:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=128)
    active = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'
```

I want to create a simple form to add a new `User`, using [Crispy Forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org), but using the default fields, `active` becomes number input field, while I would prefer to have it be a checkbox. Unfortunately, simply setting the field to `CheckboxInput` doesn't cut it, as it doesn't automatically change the on/off state to 1/0. Here's my form for context:

```
class CreateUserForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'name',
            'active',
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit'),
                HTML('<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url "app:user:list" page="1" %}">Cancel</a>'),
            ),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name', 'active']
        widgets = {
            'note': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 23, 'rows': 4}),
            'active': CheckboxInput()
        }
```

Note: All the `class`es are there for Twitter Bootstrap.

Is there a convenient way to do this? Could I maybe change the data being submitted somewhere? Or should I be taking a different approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195424/how-to-insert-a-checkbox-in-a-django-form

Comment: @JasonS Unfortunately that doesn't cover the part where MySQL wants a 1 or 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `BooleanField` instead of an `IntegerField`. This doesn't require changing the database tables because `BooleanField` internally translates booleans to 1s and 0s. MySQL's "boolean" column type is nothing more than an alias for tinyint(1) anyway, i.e. an integer type used as a 1/0 truth value. You can do this with other integer column types, too.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `clean_active` method to your form to normalize the input:

```
class CreateUserForm(ModelForm):
    ...

    def clean_active(self):
        return 1 if self.cleaned_data['active'] else 0
```

See also: [cleaning and validating form input in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/).

However, you should also ask yourself do you *really* need to represent your data in MySql in that way. It would be *way* more convenient to just use `BooleanField` instead of `IntegerField` for that field.

Comment: Sadly, it's not up to me how the database is set up, or I would change it in a heartbeat.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any effect...in fact, when I put `print "hello"` above `clean_active`'s `return`, it never printed anything. I'm looking into the link you provided more though.

Comment: There was an indentation error in my answer that would put the method outside of `CreateUserForm` class. I corrected it now. Make sure you didn't copy the error.